# Workaround for error with Link's 'as' and 'href' incompatible values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, next.js

I created the following page in my *Next.js* project: `src/pages/brand1/[[...subpages]]`. I'm using Incremental Static Regeneration, I have a `.next/server/pages/brand1.json` file after building the *next.js* project. In my component I want to create a `Link` component which when clicked, displays an URL with an empty path (for example `page-domain.com`) in the address bar and renders the page from `/brand1` route (which uses `brand1.json` file). I tried various solutions to achieve this, for example:

```
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: '/brand1',
  }}
  as={'/'}
  shallow
>
  link
</Link>
```

But I get an error in the browser saying that `Error: The provided 'as' value (/) is incompatible with the 'href' value (/brand1/[[...subpages]])`

I have the following solution which works for urls with not empty subpages (for example `page-domain.com/menu`), but it doesn't work for the root page as I described earlier:

```
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: '/brand1/[[...subpages]]',
    query: { subpages: 'menu' },
  }}
  as={'/menu'}
  shallow
>
  link
</Link>
```

My question is how to create a link which can display URL with empty path like `page-domain.com` and gets the page from the `/brand1` route?

Comment: Just as a side note: You can just write `as="/"` rather than `as={'/'}`. Easier to type. :)